# VBA Overwrite Addin Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

So I have done some research but I can't get the feature I am looking for to work.

I am deploying a workbook to a lot of people on a network.  I have an add-in on a network drive that all of the workbooks reference to.  It works great when running the macros, no problem at all.  My issue is updating the macros when people have one of the workbooks open.  People leave things open for days sometimes, I know, cause I do the same thing sometimes.

I found this link, with the code below but I can't get it to work.

https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?152-Deploying-Add-ins-in-a-Network-Environment

The macro saves it as a .xlsm or a macro enabled workbook.  It won't save it as a .xla

```
Sub DeployAddIn()
'Author       : Ken Puls (www.excelguru.ca)
'Macro Purpose: To deploy finished/updated add-in to a network
'               location as a read only file
    Dim strAddinDevelopmentPath As String
    Dim strAddinPublicPath As String

    'Set development and public paths
    strAddinDevelopmentPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    strAddinPublicPath  = "F:\Addins" & Application.PathSeparator

    'Turn off alert regarding overwriting existing files
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Save the add-in
    With ThisWorkbook
        'Save to ensure work is okay in case of a crash
        .Save

        'Save read only copy to the network (remove read only property
        'save the file and reapply the read only status)
        On Error Resume Next
        SetAttr strAddinPublicPath & .Name, vbNormal
        On Error Goto 0
        .SaveCopyAs Filename:=strAddinPublicPath  & .Name
        SetAttr strAddinPublicPath & .Name, vbReadOnly
    End With

    'Resume alerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I've tried doing

```
.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlAddIn
```

Or

```
.`SaveAs FileFormat:=18`
```

Niether of those work.  SaveCopyAs doesn't have a fileformat option.

Any suggestions or any other methods that might work?

Comment: For reference, this is the setup I have at the moment.  http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut08.htm

Comment: the link is dead, here is the wayback of it, https://web.archive.org/web/20191022132719/http://fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut08.htm.

Answer (score 0):

You keep a copy of the XLAM on your local machine that you update, and then when you are ready to deploy it, you copy the XLAM to the server. Everyone else runs off a copy that is on the server (you dont want them to copy it to their local machine, btw) - The key is that when you copy it to the server, you have to set it to read-only in the file properties. You have to do that every time you copy it. Then you can overwrite it at any time.

Comment if you have any questions - I do this every day for work.

Comment: I thought I did set it to read only but maybe I was mistaken.  Anyway to tell who is in the file so I can start from scratch?

Comment: I have never been able to find a way to tell who has the file open. If you have the option of rebooting the server, that would be the only way to disconnect them from it, but you probably do not have that option. You may have set it to read-only the first time, thinking that the setting would stay that way. It doesn't.

Comment: As a last resort, I would recommend sending an email to everyone that uses the XLAM file that it is important to remember to close Excel at the end of the day. In addition to that, you would write a simple VB.NET program that would run once an hour on a timer, checking the read-only status of the file and then attempt to make it read-only if it's not, and ignore the error you would get from the attempt. VB.NET is free and not too different from VBA.

Comment: Ok so you're saying every time I made an edit to the file and saved it I took it out of read only?

Comment: Correct. When you overwrite the read-only file with a non-read-only file, it's no longer read-only, because it's no longer the same file. You have to set it to read-only right after every time you replace it with the new file.

Comment: Also, you could create a "Deploy" function that only you use to do the copying to the server, and program it to change the read-only attribute too so you wouldn't ever forget to change the read-only attribute, but first you are going to have to get all the people who have it open to close Excel in order to get it back into read-only state.

Comment: And i just re-read your question and are trying to do just that and either you updated it, or I didn't read it all. Look up the FileSystem object. Sorry, it's getting late here. Either way, you need to get everyone to close Excel first or reboot the server.

Comment: ...and If you create a VB.NET program to check it each hour you can also have it send you an email once it is successful at setting it as read-only.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Seems to be working fine at the moment !